# PHP ZendPDF Modify Metadata XML

Tags: php, xml, symfony, pdf

I'm trying to create a PDF/A-1b in Symfony using ZendPDF

To do that I have to set some Metadata in the XML structure of the PDF. But I have no idea how to do that.

I tried to modify the XML via *DOMDocument* but when I try to add a DOMNode it says it can't write the property

```
$node = new DOMNode();
$node->nodeName = "part";
```

But then I get *Cannot write property* Exception

I just need to append a child on a DOMDocument

Complete Code

```
$metadata = $this->pdf->getMetadata();

    $metadataDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $metadataDOM->loadXML($metadata);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($metadataDOM);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'adobe:ns:meta/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xmp', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xmpGImg', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xmpTPg', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/t/pg/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('stDim', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/Dimensions#');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xmpG', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('dc', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xmpMM', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('pdf', 'http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('pdfaid', 'http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id');

    $data = $xpath->query('//rdf:Description')->item(0);

    $node = new DOMNode();
    $node->nodeName = "asdf";
    $data->appendChild($node);

    dump($data);
    dump($metadataDOM->saveXML());
    die;
```

Comment: You can never write property *`nodeName`*. So the question would be why you're trying this in the first place. And what you expected to happen instead of the error.  And if you want to improve your question, reduce the code in there to the bare minimum to establish a self-contained example that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the nodeName property is read only
see: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

defined in the domNode class here:
`public readonly string $nodeName;`

On the link bellow there is also a solution with other element that is read only "textContent"

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#95545

copy of the solution by David Rekowski from php.net:

> You cannot simply overwrite $textContent, to replace the text content
>   of a  DOMNode, as the missing readonly flag suggests. Instead you have
>   to do something like this:

```
<?php

$node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
$node->appendChild(new DOMText('new text content'));

?>

This example shows what happens:

<?php

$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML('<node>old content</node>');
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('node')->item(0);
echo "Content 1: ".$node->textContent."\n";

$node->textContent = 'new content';
echo "Content 2: ".$node->textContent."\n";

$newText = new DOMText('new content');

$node->appendChild($newText);
echo "Content 3: ".$node->textContent."\n";

$node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
$node->appendChild($newText);
echo "Content 4: ".$node->textContent."\n";

?>

The output is:

Content 1: old content // starting content
Content 2: old content // trying to replace overwriting $node->textContent
Content 3: old contentnew content // simply appending the new text node
Content 4: new content // removing firstchild before appending the new text node

If you want to have a CDATA section, use this:

<?php
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML('<node>old content</node>');
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('node')->item(0);
$node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
$newText = $doc->createCDATASection('new cdata content');
$node->appendChild($newText);
echo "Content withCDATA: ".$doc->saveXML($node)."\n";
?>
```

*btw. this question is not related to symfony at all.*

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

I created the base PDF PDF/A-1b conform and don't need to modify the metadata anymore